# Is that possible using "setAutoresizingMask" to make the view autoresizing after hiding/showing navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am doing this with the following:

```
[[self  navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

and also I didn't use IB to create view objects. But my view did not auto-resize after hiding navigation bar(there was a blank area where the navigation bar used to be)

I am wondering if I could make it auto-resize only by "setAutoresizingMask", or do I have to use some hand-writing animation stuff?

Comment: Yes, you probably can just set the autoresizing mask and everything will just work. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myView.autoresizingMask` will do exactly this for you. As soon as the navigation bar is hidden, the bounds of the superview of your views changes. This will auto-resize all subviews of the superview (and therefore all of your views) by having a look at each `autoresizingMask` of the subviews.

### Short Answer:

Make sure your views use the `autoresizingMask` and you should be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did add the autoresizingMask but it did not work for me. I am going to check my code again